# How to compare a scale free and random network?

Tags: networking, networkx

I wonder how can random and scale-free network can be somehow compared. I now the difference between those two types of network (e.g. clustering) and which parameter characterize them (gamma in the case of scale free networks and n- nb of nodes, k - number of edges for the random network). But if say, I want to compare how information spreads in those two networks, then how can I select gamma and k to get a comparable "set up" ? I don't want to get the same networks (I KNOW they have different properties), just to be able to compare them efficiently.

I was thinking of using the average number of link that I get from 10,000 scale free networks with gamma = 2, and choose the k for the random network accordingly. Does it make sense ?

ps: I'm using Networkx to generate my networks.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to compare how information spreads in those two networks

For that, you can use [efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(network_science)) ("the efficiency of a network is a measure of how efficiently it exchanges information").
You can compute this in networkx as 1/L where L is the [average shortest path length](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.average_shortest_path_length.html).

In the code below G is a scale-free graph (generated with [`scale_free_graph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.directed.scale_free_graph.html)) and H is random graph (generated with [`gnp_random_graph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.gnp_random_graph.html)). Note that both graphs have the same number of nodes (200); this way they are more comparable.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.scale_free_graph(200)
H = nx.gnp_random_graph(200, 0.5)
print("Efficiency for G:", 1.0/nx.average_shortest_path_length(G))
print("Efficiency for H:", 1.0/nx.average_shortest_path_length(H))
```

The output below will be different each time you run the code (the graphs are randomly generated). You could create multiple scale-free/random graphs, get their average efficiency and then compare the values.

```
Efficiency for G: 3.67192545437771
Efficiency for H: 0.6666890013065765
```

When comparing graphs, you can of course also use other network measures, like e.g. [average clustering](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.clustering_coefficient.average_clustering.html) etc.

Now, the question in your title.

> How to compare a scale free and random network?

I think the most intuitive way to show the difference between scale free and random networks is to plot the (ranked/sorted) node degrees.

From the image below you can immediately guess which is the scale-free and which is the random network.

[image]

I got the image with the following code (G and H are the graphs from before).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

degree_sequence = sorted(nx.degree(G).values(), reverse=True)
plt.plot(degree_sequence, 'b-')

degree_sequence = sorted(nx.degree(H).values(), reverse=True)
plt.plot(degree_sequence, 'r-')

plt.ylabel("degree")
plt.xlabel("rank")
plt.show()
```

You will of course get a slightly different image since the node degrees (`degree_sequence`) depend on the randomly generated graphs.

A final tip: if you're going to plot multiple scale-free graphs consider using a log-log plot.